# Access: export to excel with sub table

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I am trying to export data from the company database.

I need to give my researchers access to data from 2 tables.

These tables include information about websites and our assessment of them.
In the sub table we have URL's for various aspects.

I want to be able to export both data so they can quickly navigate to the sites rather than having to search for them ever time.

So far I can export the primary table but not the sub table too.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated! :)

Regards, Mikey.

Comment: Access, SQL, mySQL are all named here.  Where are the tables, and where are you trying to get them to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are going to have to do is in Access, create a new query linking the two tables together (hopefully you have some field that links the two tables together) - and then export that query result set to excel.

Comment: Many thanks for this solution.  It will help me out in many areas. :-)